# Admiration at their novelty

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase *Admiration at their novelty means respect for your success* mean?

Context:

*In your affairs, create suspense.  Admiration at their novelty means respect for your success.  It's neither useful nor pleasurable to show all your cards.* -Baltasar Gracian

Comment: Absent context this question is unanswerable. It might wind up being idiosyncratic anyway, in which case who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sense of this is that "admiration at their novelty" refers to "your affairs." By not revealing how you manage or execute your affairs leaves an air of mystery to befuddle your acquaintances, so that "admiration at their novelty"—meaning the newness (to others) of how you go about things—leaves people feeling that your methods cannot be dismissed, because they haven't seen such things before.